# No sound from vlc python script on raspberry pi 4 invoked via rc.local

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, vlc, boot, raspberry-pi4

I want to use my headless raspberry pi 4 as an online radio player. The python script works and the raspberry outputs audio if I run it from terminal, but I tried running it from /etc/rc.local and with crontab after boot, it seems to work, however there is no sound. Do you know how to run it after boot to output sound?

Thank you!

```
import vlc
import time

url = 'http://www.icast.connectmedia.hu/4748/mr7.mp3'
#define VLC instance
instance = vlc.Instance()

#Define VLC player
player=instance.media_player_new()

#Define VLC media
media=instance.media_new(url)

#Set player media
player.set_media(media)

#Play the media
player.play()


#Sleep for 5 sec for VLC to complete retries.
time.sleep(5)
#Get current state.
state = str(player.get_state())

while state == 'State.Playing':
    state = str(player.get_state())
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Which distro, and which specific version of that distro? Raspian? Something else? We need to know the distro to know which sound daemon it uses (if any), and how service management is done (ideally it uses systemd or something like it; `rc.local` gives you no automated restart, no failure detection, no dependency management control, and is otherwise best avoided; back when systemd didn't exist, Doing It Right meant DJB daemontools, or Runit, or Upstart, or otherwise using a real process supervision system).

Comment: ...once we know which sound daemon your distro ships, the next question is whether it relies on environment variables or such to find the socket (and whether there's a system-level service already available, or if it's configured out-of-the-box as a per-user service).

Comment: It runs on Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster).

Comment: ...okay, so that's Debian-based. Unless it has a different init system than upstream, then, it probably *does* use systemd; can you verify that? (Is there a `systemctl` command? Does running it spit out a list of services?)

Comment: Okay, PulseAudio's developers recommend not running it in system mode, so that's why it presumably won't be running on your system until someone logs in at the GUI in a default out-of-the-box install (assuming the Raspian/Debian packagers are following upstream guidance, which is the way to bet without contrary knowledge).

Comment: The related [unix.se] question [PulseAudio as system-wide systemd service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338687/pulseaudio-as-system-wide-systemd-service) might be worthwhile reading. Similarly, the upstream docs at https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/WhatIsWrongWithSystemWide/ explaining why they don't suggest that for most users, and when it actually *is* appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, after another few hours of searching I found the solution on this topic, which seems to work as I wanted: [link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40637/restart-mplayer-stream-process-on-loss-of-internet-connection/40660)

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to play the online stream after boot by installing mplayer and adding `sudo mplayer -loop 0 'http://www.icast.connectmedia.hu/4748/mr7.mp3'` to `/etc/rc.local`. Maybe some services are not started when the python script runs vlc as @CharlesDuffy mentioned, so it does not produce any sound.